# Prevent re-sizing of charts when column and row dimensions are changed

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have plotted many charts on a sheet. The chart dimensions are fixed mentioning the chart should be how many rows and columns wide. 
The charts are plotted with these dimensions; but if the column width or row width is changed, then the chart dimensions increase accordingly. I want a code which will not resize the chart on further changes with the column and row dimension changes once the charts have been plotted according to original row and column dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the charts to Free Floating, so they do not resize in response to row and column changes.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("YourChartName").Placement = xlFreeFloating
```

Do this for each of the charts.

You can also do the same, manually, without VBA. Right-click a chart and select Format Chart Options. Then, under Properties, select "Don't move or size with cells."